# Could someone explain to me why this solution is correct/ how you get to this solution?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$\left|\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:|x|<10\}\right| = 19.$$

Find the following cardinalities.

Comment: Your query has already received 3 downvotes.  It is worth explaining why. (1) "It said something about a to b inclusive but I have no idea what that means." It's a good idea to not omit any info regarding the problem that *may* be pertinent. (2) Your query showed **no work** : see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:|x|<10\}$ means all the integers whose absolute value is less than $10$.  Writing $\left|\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:|x|<10\}\right|$ means the size of that set, i.e. how many integers are there whose absolute value is less than $10$?  Well, we can list them out: $-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and count them, there are $19$.  Alternatively, we want the number of integers between $-9$ and $9$, inclusive, which we can calculate by $9 - (-9) + 1 = 19$.